# CORS node js and apache server

Tags: javascript, node.js, apache, cors

I am currently hosting a website on an apache server (on top of arch if that's relavent). What I need is to be able to call a small little node script (which will eventually send an email) after clicking a button on one of the web pages.

It currently works as follows

### clientside.js

```
$('#some-long-stupid-unique-name').click(function(){
$.ajax({
    type: 'POST',
    url: 'http://localhost:8081/sendMail'
});
});
```

### mail.js

```
var cors = require('cors');

var express = require('express');
var app = express();
app.use(cors());

app.post('/sendMail', function(req, res) {
    //req.header("Access-Control-Allow-Origin", "*");
    //res.header("Access-Control-Allow-Origin", "*");
    //res.header("Access-Control-Allow-Headers", "Origin, X-Requested-With, Content-Type, Accept");
    //next();
    console.log("Button pressed :D");
    res.json({ "A": "value"});

//run code here
});


app.listen(8081);
```

which is started by running `node mail.js &` and the apache server is started using `systemctl restart httpd.service`

### button.html

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head> 
    <title> some title</title>
</head>

<body>
    <div>
        <button id="some-long-stupid-unique-name" class="btn-default btn-sm back_to_options">Test</button>
    </div>
</body>
</html>
```

however, within firefox, whenever I click on the test button I see `Cross-Origin Request Blocked: The Same Origin Policy diallows reading the remote resource at http://localhost:8081/sendMail. (Reason CORS request did not succeed.)`

I cannot for the life of me figure out what it is that I am doing wrong :/

I am assuming that I need to configure the node to accept cors but the more and more I try I wonder if this is incorrect and I actually need to fix it within apache?

Also could a simple firewall within iptables effect this as well?

Edit 1: Updated mail.js

Edit 2: Update mail.js

Edit 3: Update mail.js

Comment: I presume the port numbers are different that's it is not treated as same origin. So I presume apache listening to 80 and you are sending a post request to 8081, in that case, make sure 'cors' in fact sends the header "Access-Control-Allow-Origin: *". Check the presence of this header on network tab. If it is not there you need to add it.

Comment: hmmmm it doesn't look like it's present in the network tab, this is the guide I've been using https://www.npmjs.com/package/cors, I don't really see anywhere I can specify to send specific headers using cors. Could I get a push in the right direction for this?

Comment: From the express.js side, you need to set that, I guess something along these lines:  `req.headers['Access-Control-Allow-Origin'] = '*'`. Search for setting request header. Note that HTTP headers are case INSENSITIVE.

Comment: @ibrahimtanyalcin I have updated my original post to what I currently have, but I still am not seeing the header in network tabs :/

Comment: This can help seems like you need both headers: https://dzone.com/articles/cors-in-node

Comment: Thanks for the link, it was a good read :), but unfortunatley I am getting the same error

Answer (score 0):

You have four things you should not have and are missing one thing you need:

---

The following are redundant. You are using the CORS middleware module.

Remove these.

> ```
> req.header("Access-Control-Allow-Origin", "*");
> res.header("Access-Control-Allow-Origin", "*");
> res.header("Access-Control-Allow-Headers", "Origin, X-Requested-With, Content-Type, Accept");
> ```

---

This:

> ```
> next();
> ```

… is used when you are writing middleware. Not an endpoint. Here it throws a 500 error which makes the CORS test fail.

Remove it.

---

Now you need to make your endpoint respond to the request with something.

The response headers set by the CORS module are pointless if there is no response.

```
app.post('/sendMail', function(req, res) {
    console.log("Button pressed :D");
    res.json({ "some": "data"});
});
```

Comment: I've updated the post with your edits. My apologies if i'm just being obtuse, or not giving necessary information. But I am still getting the same cors error as originally stated